# Extension function with different signature is confusing with different extension function in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, kotlin-extension

```
class Example

fun main(){

    val example: Example = Example()

    // what function i am calling is it fun Example.extensionFun() ?
    // Or is it Example.extensionFun(string: String) ?
    example.extensionFun()

}

// first extension function
fun Example.extensionFun(){
   println("Hey i'm first extension function")
}

// second extension function
fun Example.extensionFun(testArgument: String = "test argument "){ // argument just to change the function signature
    println("Hey i'm second extension function ")
}
```

In the above example i have created two extension function with the same name but different signature.
When i try to call ->

```
example.extensionFun()
```

then IDE just calls the "fun Example.extensionFun()"

but even if i try to call

```
fun  Example.extensionFun(testArgument: String ="test argument")
```

[image]

by using code completion pop up  and selecting second extension function it is again calling

```
fun Example.extensionFun()
```

and thus it left me single way to call the second extension function which is by passing the different value for the testArgumet (argument). for eg.

```
example.extensionFun("different value")
```

but there is many cases where we don't want to change the default value of the function parameter when we are calling it.

I think i found a bug  but kindly please share your opinion

Comment: This isn't a bug. The *compiler/language*, not the IDE, has no way to know which method you mean to call if you call it without a string. In other words, the code is truly ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it's ambiguous, the compiler calls the overload that has fewer arguments. In fact, I don't think it even generates overloads for function signatures that are already explicitly declared. They should probably provide a compiler warning to let you know the default value is pointless, but maybe that was deemed too expensive for compile times.

Your only option is to use a different function name to break the ambiguity.